# How to convert SQL result set to JSON in Groovy?

Tags: sql, json, groovy

I have this simple Groovy script to export SQL result set to JSON. Though the below one works, it is not in the format I would like to have. Any help here please?

```
def resultset = Sql.newInstance(...).rows('select * from client')
println new JsonBuilder(resultset).toPrettyString()
```

**Above code prints**

```
  [
      {
        "ID":1,
        "NAME: "ABC"
      },
      {
        "ID":2,
        "NAME: "XYZ"
      },
      {
        "ID":3,
        "NAME: "MSFT"
    }
]
```

**Expected output**

```
{
    "clients": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "NAME": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "NAME": "XYZ"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "NAME": "MSFT"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The second code snippet is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry, it is fixed and is a valid JSON now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wouldn't is just be:

```
println new JsonBuilder(clients:resultset).toPrettyString()
```

You know what's going on here? You pass an instance of a `Map` to `JsonBuilder` and that's all.